# Accessing Azure VM port from Outside of VM

Tags: azure, cloud, azure-virtual-machine, inbound-security-rule

As we know there are simple steps to give access to any VM-port from outside.

Here is the steps I have already covered :

1. Open VM instance and run the server on port 80 and checked the
   localhost is running in the local browse,
2. added port 80 in the inbound of Network security group,
3. turned off all three types of firewall from the VM windows.

[image]

Still the public ip is not accisible from the outside. Ping ... is resulting "Request timeout" or the port "80" is not accessible from the browser using public IP.

Edit : Surprisingly i have found a Deny tag in the report ! Does it matter ?

Comment: You generally can't ping VM resources in azure unless it is internal to a virtual network.  Do you have a load balancer in front of this VM?

Comment: @CtrlDot No Load balancer. But what about accessing the port from the browser ? It is accessible as localhost in the local instance.

Comment: Can you access the website from another VM in the same VNET? (IE using private ip address rather than public)?

Comment: inside vm instance (windows 2016 server) I am able to open localhost using browser installed in it.

Comment: Your VM deploy in Classic module or ARM module? If your VM deploy in Classic Module, we should add endpoints to it.

Comment: No! Not in classic vm @JasonYe-MSFT

Comment: @SagiruddinMondal ok, please use command `netstat -ant` to check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, add port 80 to NSG inbound rules and turn off VM's windows firewall, we will access website from outside.

In your scenario, maybe we should check web site work on IPv4 or IPv6 or both?
We can use this command to check it:

```
C:\Users\jason>netstat -ant
Active Connections

  Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State           Offload State

  TCP    0.0.0.0:80             0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       InHost
  TCP    0.0.0.0:135            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       InHost
  TCP    0.0.0.0:445            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       InHost
  TCP    0.0.0.0:3389           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       InHost
  TCP    [::]:80                [::]:0                 LISTENING       InHost
  TCP    [::]:135               [::]:0                 LISTENING       InHost
  TCP    [::]:445               [::]:0                 LISTENING       InHost
  TCP    [::]:3389              [::]:0                 LISTENING       InHost
```

We can find web service listen on port 80 and work on IPv4 and IPv6, so we can use IPv4(public IP address) and port 80 to access this web site.

We should make sure web service work on IPv4.

==========================

**Update**:

Please check your Vnet-->subnet, does this subnet associated with a NSG, if yes, we should modify this NSG's inbound rules, add port 80 to this NSG.

It seems a issue with node server for angular cli, more information please refer to this link below:
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1793

Comment: I will check soon and let you know brother.. thanks for the post.

Comment: Hey Bro I have updated the question. Can you please check. I have checked the command there is no TCP 0.0.0.0:80

Comment: @SagiruddinMondal please try to use http://127.0.0.1 to browse your web site in your VM.

Comment: Yes it is accessible by 127.0.0.1 !

Comment: @SagiruddinMondal could your please show your IIS bindings setting?

Comment: I am using ng serve (node server for angular cli) I guess I have not bound to IIS !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143749/discussion-between-jason-ye-msft-and-sagiruddin-mondal).

Comment: You can add new rule inbound section of firewall and can mention required ports which need to be allowed.